# Simple webapp compatible with google app engine

Tags: database, linux, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have to develop one simple app compatible with google app engine and ubuntu server...
well I'm using webapp2 with no problem both ubuntu and gae.

My problem is database, I'd like to use the same syntax

eg.

```
class Greeting(db.Model):

  author = db.UserProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

that I use in gae with mysql (or.. maybe others), 
but I like that working also outside (on ubuntu)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/) and [CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf/).

Update: CapeDwarf if java-only.

Comment: I'm looking for a lib or other "stuff" that support db I run under nginx varnish and so on

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you would like to deploy a appengine app with ubuntu server? I did look into that and there are a few options running the app server, threading might be an issue but there has been a few releases with improvements
You can use SQLLite or MySQL depending on the setup

```
dev_appserver.py --address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I have installed nginx I won't use any others :)

Comment: You can probably use a http proxy, haven't tried it myself but I see no reason it shouldn't work

Comment: Hi, no my problem is to have a DAL not a new webserver :)